# How to configure nginx and passenger to rails application in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, passenger

**Passenger nginx configration in docker environment**

In my rails application I want to configure the nginx and passenger in docker environment. I am able to make progress all configration expect this part. Please suggest some one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this gem. It has most of what you need. 
I've used it as a starter and it worked for me.

https://github.com/pacuna/dckerize